# Manual crop is not working when authenticated user adds a new content

Tags: media

I am using the [Manual Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/manualcrop) module in my site. Admin and authenticated user can add a content. If admin adds a new content, manual crop enable after picture uploading. But when authenticated user adds a new content manual crop module is disable.

It enable only after save content. After saving content error message comes like this: "Chose cropping styles".

What can I do in this moment in order to do enable cropping after uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Manual Crop (currently) doesn't have any permissions of itself, the File entity permissions are only required if you're using the Media module.
If you're using an administration theme for node adding and editing, then the users that are allowed to edit nodes should have access to it.

Comment: How to configure media module